# Flutter: How to pass a TextField text to an API request?

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart, request, future

I am learning Flutter, so I made a fun little News app with the [news API](http://newsapi.org). It has different tabs for different categories and it requests the data based on the keyword associated with each tab. However, I want a tab where users can search for news based on the specific keyword. My issue is that my `Resource` (shown below) is static, so I can't pass things to it, and I'm not sure if/how I could make without the `Resource` being static. I won't overload with my code, I'm just looking for a little guidance based on what I'm aiming for. My best guess is using `Future` in some way, but I am not sure what that would look like in this case.

If more code is necessary, I'd be happy to provide it. I don't like too much clutter in my questions. Any ideas? Thanks! Here is the most important code:

```
  static chooseURL(keyword) {
    if (keyword == 'General') {
      return Constants.HEADLINE_NEWS_URL.substring(0, 37) + "country=us" +
          Constants.HEADLINE_NEWS_URL.substring(
              39, Constants.HEADLINE_NEWS_URL.length);
    } else if(keyword == 'Search') {
      // No idea!
    } else {
      return Constants.HEADLINE_NEWS_URL.substring(0, 39) +
          keyword.toLowerCase() + Constants.HEADLINE_NEWS_URL.substring(
          39, Constants.HEADLINE_NEWS_URL.length);
    }
  }

  static Resource<List<NewsArticle>> all(key) {
    return Resource(
        url: chooseURL(key),
        parse: (response) {
          final result = json.decode(response.body);
          Iterable list = result['articles'];
          return list.map((model) => NewsArticle.fromJson(model)).toList();
        });
  }
```

And this:

```
  void _populateNewsArticles() {
    WebService().load(NewsArticle.all(keyword)).then((newsArticles) => {
      setState(() {
        _newsArticles = newsArticles;
      })
    });
  }
```

Comment: Why are your methods static? What class are they in?

Comment: @Abion47 If they are not static, `_populateNewsArticles()` raises the error: `Instance member all can't be accessed using static access.` They are part of the class `NewsArticle`.

Comment: What class does the TextField exist in? The same class as `_populateNewsArticles`?

Comment: No, it exists in a higher up widget, but it can easily be called. But I may have figured out how to make it non-static, so don't sweat it right now I might have figured it out. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: If `NewsArticle` is a service class for getting news data, my recommendation would be to convert it into a singleton instead of having a bunch of static methods. Regardless, though, to do what you want, make another method called `get` or something that you can pass the filter string to.